# Is there a way to get inactive products with amazon MWS API?

Tags: php, amazon-mws

I have quite a lot of products in the 'Inactive' section with the alert 'Potential high pricing'.

Is there a way to get these products via amazon MWS? I tried a couple of reports such as

`GET_MERCHANT_LISTINGS_INACTIVE_DATA`

`GET_MERCHANT_CANCELLED_LISTINGS_DATA`

`GET_MERCHANT_LISTINGS_DEFECT_DATA`

but these don't actually give me all the products and give alot of other information. Also, by navigating to `Price Health` I can see every products that i'm interested in, Is there a to export these or get them via MWS API?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I believe you can get all products including inactive products. Try these four. I'm almost positive I came across this a while ago but I'm not sure which it was:

1. *GET_FBA_MYI_UNSUPPRESSED_INVENTORY_DATA*
2. *GET_MERCHANT_LISTINGS_DATA_LITE*
3. *GET_FBA_FULFILLMENT_MONTHLY_INVENTORY_DATA*
4. *GET_MERCHANT_LISTINGS_ALL_DATA*